# How to unzip a zip file which contains multiple folders using ssziparchive?

Tags: ios, unzip, ssziparchive

I am trying to unzip a folder using ssziparchive lib I found at: https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive. The code I used:

```
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ZippSecretExcel.zip"];
     NSString *unzipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UnZipSecretExcel"];
    BOOL
    status = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipFilePath toDestination:unzipFilePath];
    if(status)
    {
        NSLog(@"File successfully uncompressed");
    }
    else{
          NSLog(@"File failed to compressed"); 
    }
```

I checked ZippSecretExcel exists in projects document directory, but the above code fail to unzip it.The program compiles and there is no error or crash. My zip folder contains three folders which themselves contain files and folders. Do I have to perform any additional step to unzip the file?

Answer (score 0):

Will this code 'status = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipFilePath toDestination:unzipFilePath];'  create a directory first for the destination path ?..

If not , use the below code to create folder before unzip

```
BOOL isDire = YES;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];            
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:unzipFilePath isDirectory:&isDire]){

[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:unzipFilePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];

}
```

Comment: The zip folder that I was using was corrupted. The code I used worked when I used a different zip folder.